# Android app crash for mobiles which do not support google api

Tags: android

My app supports google apis.works fine in phones and emulators which support this. but if i try to run it on a emulator which does not support google api....app crashes.

Comment: you should post exception log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen if your app uses:

1. Google Maps
2. GCM
3. In app billing
4. LVL
5. Any other Google services that qualify under Google APIs

On devices, rule of the thumb is that if the device comes with Google Play, it'll have the Google APIs.